# Custom OWL component, Reuse Kanban views Components

Tags: odoo, odoo-16, odoo-owl

I'm a backend developer trying to learn OWL framework.

I'm doing something like the Odoo playground tutorial. The idea is to have a custom qweb template render, where i put my custom components, but not having the Odoo client loaded.

So i have the menús and my custom qweb template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="custom_ui_template" name="Custom Delivery Template">
        <html>
            <head>
                <!-- <t t-call-assets="web.assets_common"/>
                <t t-call-assets="web.assets_backend"/> -->
                <t t-call-assets="owl_tutorial.custom_ui"/>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
        </html>
            
    </template>
    

    <record id="action_open_custom_ui" model="ir.actions.act_url">
            <field name="name">Custom UI</field>
            <field name="url">/custom/ui</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem 
        name="Custom UI"
        id="menu_open_custom_ui"
        parent="owl_tutorial.menu_owl_tutorial"
        action="action_open_custom_ui"
        sequence="99"/>
</odoo>
```

And the controller to render that template:

```py
    @http.route('/custom/ui', type='http', auth='user', website=True)
    def delivery_ui(self, **kw):
        return request.render('owl_tutorial.custom_ui_template', {})
```

And my assets declaration in the **manifest**.py, like playground tutorial

```py
 'owl_tutorial.custom_ui': [
            # bootstrap
            ('include', 'web._assets_helpers'),
            'web/static/src/scss/pre_variables.scss',
            'web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss',
            ('include', 'web._assets_bootstrap'),

            'web/static/src/libs/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css', # required for fa icons
            'web/static/src/legacy/js/promise_extension.js', # required by boot.js
            'web/static/src/boot.js', # odoo module system
            'web/static/src/env.js', # required for services
            'web/static/src/session.js', # expose __session_info__ containing server information
            'web/static/lib/owl/owl.js', # owl library
            'web/static/lib/owl/odoo_module.js', # to be able to import "@odoo/owl"
            'web/static/src/core/utils/functions.js',
            'web/static/src/core/browser/browser.js',
            'web/static/src/core/registry.js',
            'web/static/src/core/assets.js',

            'owl_tutorial/static/src/custom_ui/*.js',
            'owl_tutorial/static/src/custom_ui/*.xml',
            'owl_tutorial/static/src/custom_ui/*.scss',
        ],
```

My OWL Component:
custom_ui.js

```js
/** @odoo-module */
import { Component, useState } from "@odoo/owl";
const { xml, mount } = owl;

export class TestComponent extends Component {
    static template = "owl_tutorial.test_ui"
    setup(){
        super.setup()
        console.log("This is Test Component")
    }
    showStockPickingKanban() {
        // TODO
    }

    showOdooKanban() {
       // TODO
    }
    returnToOdooBackend() {
        // Redirige al backend de Odoo
        window.location.href = "/web";
    }
}
```

custom_ui.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="owl_tutorial.test_ui" owl="1">
        <div>
            <div class="custom-buttons">
                <button t-on-click="showStockPickingKanban">Kanban Stock Picking</button>
                <button t-on-click="showOdooKanban">Kanban Odoo</button>
                <button t-on-click="returnToOdooBackend">Close</button>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-kanban">
                <t t-set="domain" t-value="[]"/>
                    <t t-attf-kanban-model="stock.picking"/>
                    <t t-attf-kanban-model="res.partner"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

And the main.js to mount the main component to my qweb template body

```js
/** @odoo-module */
import { TestComponent } from "./custom_ui";
import { mount } from "@odoo/owl";

import { templates } from "@web/core/assets"


// Me lo está montando en general, en lugar de solo en mi palntilla
owl.whenReady(() => {
    const config = { templates, dev: true }
    mount(TestComponent, document.body, config)
});
```

I would like to reuse the actions and views that are defined in Odoo, so one button display the kanban view stock.picking, and the other the same for res.partner.

I know i can import KanbanController, and KanbanView from Odoo web components, buy i dont know how to use inside my custom_ui component.

¿Can I modify te domain, the context...?¿I need to add the code in javascript file or use sometthing like <KanbanView> in my xml?

The objetive is to render the desired views in the div below the buttons div so i can learn how to reuse the Odoo conponents mixed with muy custom components.